# Cannot unzip zip file in DockerFile as non root user

Tags: docker

I keep getting the below error when I try to unzip a zip file in my DockerFile

```
checkdir error:  cannot create my-archive
                 Permission denied
                 unable to process my-archive/data/sample.jar
The command '/bin/sh -c unzip /home/kong/my-archive.zip' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

In my DockerFile I have:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash kong
RUN echo "kong:password" | chpasswd
RUN adduser kong sudo
USER kong
RUN wget "${url}/my-archive.zip" -P /home/kong
RUN unzip /home/kong/my-archive.zip
```

It works if I do:

```
USER root
RUN unzip /home/kong/my-archive.zip
```

but I would like to be able to do this as a non root user.

Why does it fail as non root user `kong`?

Comment: Permissions, presumably. You created the file as root, so the owner and group are likely root and root. The obvious solution would be to do the wget as kong, too.

Comment: Tried that and updated post same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to unzip the archive in the / folder.

In fact, the `unzip` command unzips the archive by default in the current directory.

Plus, the zip file is downloaded as root and might not be readable by the kong user.

Try changing your Dockerfile as follows:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash kong
RUN echo "kong:password" | chpasswd
RUN adduser kong sudo
USER kong
WORKDIR /home/kong
RUN wget "${url}/my-archive.zip" -P /home/kong
RUN unzip /home/kong/my-archive.zip
```

This way, the .zip file will be owned by the kong user and you will unzip it in his home directory.