# MSBuild webdeploy package output zip file is inaccessible

Tags: docker, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have created a custom Docker image containing VS Build tools. When I run the container to build a VS sln file using msbuild, it generates a deployment package. All the files in the output folder except the .zip are accessible. When I see the properties of .zip file and click Security tab in the dialog, it shows "You must have Read permissions to view the properties of this object". All other files don't have this issue like SourceManifest, deploy-readme, SetParameters and deploy cmd file.

This is my docker command:

```
docker run -i --rm --name myweb -w C:/users/Administrator/Documents -v "$(Agent.BuildDirectory):c:/users/Administrator/Documents/myweb:rw" vsbuildtools2017:web-v1 msbuild "myweb\s\CSS.sln" /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=myweb\s\css.sln-build.log" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="release" /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:PackageLocation="c:/users/Administrator/Documents/cssweb/a/PublishedPackage"
```

If I run the MSBuild command outside of container, it works like a charm.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's an permission issue. Just reference this  thread: [Cannot unzip zip file in DockerFile as non root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355539/cannot-unzip-zip-file-in-dockerfile-as-non-root-user) and try changing the Dockerfile.

> The zip file is downloaded as root and might not be readable by the
>   kong user.
>
> Try changing your Dockerfile as follows:
>
> ```
> RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash kong
> RUN echo "kong:password" | chpasswd
> RUN adduser kong sudo
> USER kong
> WORKDIR /home/kong
> RUN wget "${url}/my-archive.zip" -P /home/kong
> RUN unzip /home/kong/my-archive.zip
> ```
>
> This way, the .zip file will be owned by the kong user and you will
>   unzip it in his's home directory.

Another similar thread for your reference: [Web deploy package zip file does not inherit permissions from parent folder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0818bd28-c9d6-4e52-ac00-25871e9c84d0/web-deploy-package-zip-file-does-not-inherit-permissions-from-parent-folder?forum=msbuild)